# How to get points from JSON Request

Tags: android, json, api

I'm trying to draw a polyline between two places using an optimal route.

There are two or more points between source and destination.

Can someone tell me how to get points in the `polyline` using JSONObject/JSONArray in Android Studio?

```
  {
    routes": [
    {
        "bounds": {
            "northeast": {
                "lat": 17.4961254,
                "lng": 78.44918179999999
            },
            "southwest": {
                "lat": 17.4177332,
                "lng": 78.3743566
            }
        },
        "copyrights": "Map data ©2019 Google",
        "legs": [
            {
                "distance": {
                    "text": "10.2 km",
                    "value": 10201
                },
                "duration": {
                    "text": "25 mins",
                    "value": 1527
                },
                "end_address": "207, National Highway 65, Near South India Shopping Mall, A.S.Raju Nagar, Vivekananda Nagar, Kukatpally, Hyderabad, Telangana 500072, India",
                "end_location": {
                    "lat": 17.4929352,
                    "lng": 78.4053682
                },
                "start_address": "7-1-212/A/49/1, ShivBagh, Ameerpet, Hyderabad, Telangana 500016, India",
                "start_location": {
                    "lat": 17.440171,
                    "lng": 78.44918179999999
                },
                "steps": [
                    {
                        "distance": {
                            "text": "89 m",
                            "value": 89
                        },
                        "duration": {
                            "text": "1 min",
                            "value": 45
                        },
                        "end_location": {
                            "lat": 17.4393871,
                            "lng": 78.4489992
                        },
                        "html_instructions": "Head <b>south</b> on <b>Shivbagh Colony Road</b>",
                        "polyline": {
                            "points": "ahmiBkby}MdAPtAP"
                        },
                        "start_location": {
                            "lat": 17.440171,
                            "lng": 78.44918179999999
                        },
                        "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
                    },
                    {
                        "distance": {
                            "text": "76 m",
                            "value": 76
                        },
                        "duration": {
                            "text": "1 min",
                            "value": 36
                        },
                        "end_location": {
                            "lat": 17.4395305,
                            "lng": 78.4483012
                        },
                        "html_instructions": "Turn <b>right</b> toward <b>Balkampet Rd</b>",
                        "maneuver": "turn-right",
                        "polyline": {
                            "points": "ecmiBgay}MKdAOdA"
                        },
                        "start_location": {
                            "lat": 17.4393871,
                            "lng": 78.4489992
                        },
                        "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
                    },
                    {
                        "distance": {
                            "text": "0.2 km",
                            "value": 230
                        },
                        "duration": {
                            "text": "1 min",
                            "value": 65
                        },
                        "end_location": {
                            "lat": 17.4374767,
                            "lng": 78.4482884
                        },
                        "html_instructions": "Turn <b>left</b> onto <b>Balkampet Rd</b><div style=\"font-size:0.9em\">Pass by Sai Nirvana (on the left)</div>",
                        "maneuver": "turn-left",
                        "polyline": {
                            "points": "admiB{|x}MfA@b@Ab@AbE@d@?NFNE"
                        },
                        "start_location": {
                            "lat": 17.4395305,
                            "lng": 78.4483012
                        },
                        "travel_mode": "DRIVING"
                    },
                    {
                        "distance": {
                            "text": "0.5 km",
                            "value": 462
                        },
                        "duration": {
                            "text": "2 mins",
                            "value": 98
                        }.........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve all points from json by using below code. Please check this code and correct json parameters as per your required.

```
ArrayList<LatLng> listLatLong = new ArrayList<>();

try {

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result.toString());

    JSONArray results = json.getJSONArray("routes");
    JSONObject jObjResults = results.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONArray jArrLegs = jObjResults.getJSONArray("legs");

    JSONObject jObj = jArrLegs.getJSONObject(0);

    JSONArray jSteps = jObj.getJSONArray("steps");

    for (int i = 0; i < jSteps.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jObjStep = jSteps.getJSONObject(i);
        listLatLong.addAll(decodePoly(jObjStep.getJSONObject("polyline").getString("points")));
    }
} catch (Exception ignore) {

}
```

> You can draw route on your map using

```
PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(10).color(Color.BLUE);

for (int j = 0; j < listLatLong.size(); j++)
    rectLine.add(listLatLong.get(j));

mGoogleMap.addPolyline(rectLine);
```

> decodePoly() method

```
public static ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

    ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<>();

    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dLat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dLat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dLng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dLng;

        LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                (((double) lng / 1E5)));
        poly.add(p);
    }

    return poly;
}
```

Let me know if you need any more help from me.